# What did "share nothing" mode real mean?

Tags: amazon-redshift, greenplum

We called Greenplum,Redshift MPP or share nothing.
but i really dont understand why?
if it mean during a mutil-level join query，one host are computing all the time,no hosts exchange data each other?,there is no shuffle?
and or other situation.
whats the crux means of "share nothing"?

Answer (score 1):

Shared nothing means that no two servers share the same data (aside from mirrors for high availability).  A simple example would be a two node cluster where the data is distributed by gender_code.  Node1 would have all of the males and node2 would have all of the females.

In the real world, you have way more nodes than just two so you distribute the data by something like an ID column.  This gives you an even distribution of data across all of the nodes.

As you can probably guess, the optimizer has to be pretty smart to reduce the amount of data movement needed to execute a query.  It also needs to slice the query into multiple parts so that it can execute the multiple slices of the query at once.  Greenplum has been around for over 10 years and has a mature optimizer which can execute a wide variety of queries pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

"Shared Nothing" is a description of what resources are shared between the processes running in parallel. So you may have shared memory approaches running on a single host, shared storage between multiple hosts or self contained systems with their own processing, RAM and storage. A deployment based a a few of these self contained systems would be described as "shared nothing".

In a shared-nothing system each node will store a subset of the data. Query planners in these systems try to do as much work as possible on the same host the data is stored on and move or shuffle as little data as possible (on Greenplum systems these steps in the query plan are called motions).

Answer (score 0):

We call MPP 'Shared Nothing' as a way to compare Greenplum to something with a 'Shared Everything' architecture like Oracle RAC which also has multiple servers in a cluster but they all connect back to the same set of datafiles.